# Kubernetes - not enabled - with Docker for desktop (windows 10) but "kubectl cluster-info" works? Why?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-windows

I uninstalled Docker and installed it again (using the stable release channel).

Is it normal that the command "kubectl cluster-info" shows the output:

```
Kubernetes master is running at https://localhost:6445
```

**But** Kubernetes is not enabled in the Docker settings.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it show any of the other values? Disabling Docker's Kubernetes probably doesn't remove it from your kubeconfig file.

Comment: I did not disabled it but uninstalled Docker completely. I checked, and the ~\.kube folder was removed in the process.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your case.

If you install Docker on Windows10 without any other Kubernetes configuration it will return output:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:8080
```

When you will enable Kubernetes in Docker for Windows you will receive output:

```
$ kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at http://localhost:6445
KubeDNS is running at https://localhost:6445/api/v1/namespace/kube-system/services/kube-dns/proxy
```

After reinstall I have checked current kubernetes config and it was as below
$ kubectl config view

In config you will still have

```
...
   server: https://localhost:6445
...
```

Even after I deleted docker via Control Panel I still had `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.docker` and `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\.kube` directories with config.

To back to default you need to delete Docker, remove manually .docker and .kube directories with configs and install docker.

Comment: Wow!  This is some looking into it.